# Como criar uma interface de usuário com o mesmo estilo que foi utilizado no Visual Studio, Office 2013, GitHub for Windows, etc?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, wpf, temas, office-2013

Eu gostaria de saber como criar UI como as utilizadas pelo Visual Studio, Office 2013, GitHub for Windows, etc.

Procurei pela internet e encontrei um tema para WPF chamado Cosmopolitan Theme, mas observando alguns detalhes você percebe que não é o mesmo, e acho que por ser um projeto de terceiros a Microsoft não o teria utilizado para fazer o VS2012/VS2013 e o Office 2013.

Para mostrar a diferença tirei umas capturas de tela destes programas:

#### Interface que quero construir:

- Visual Studio:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Office 2013 (Excel):
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- GitHub for Windows:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Interface comum:

[image]

A diferença entre esses programas está no estilo de suas interfaces de usuário. Eu já procurei se existe algum template no Visual Studio Express for Windows 8, Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop, Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 e Ultimate 2013, mas aparentemente não existe um template do tipo.

Aparentemente esses UIs são uma customização de WPF, mas não consigo encontrar nada oficial referente a isso.

Qual o nome desse "tema"? Qualquer um pode utiliza-lo ou é algo pago? Ele á algo tipo o Ribbon que foi utilizado pela primeira vez (eu acho) no Office 2007?

Comment: [As respostas do SO em inglês lhe foram úteis?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15546599/1316620)

Comment: @talles não, pois todas elas sugeriram tecnologias de terceiros.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No caso do GitHub** a equipe do GitHub postou no blog deles como eles fizeram o layout, como desenharam e fizeram o xaml. [Leia aqui](https://github.com/blog/1151-designing-github-for-windows).

Segundo [outra postagem no blog deles](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows) para fazer a parte visual eles usaram dois frameworks: [Calibur.Micro](https://github.com/BlueSpire/Caliburn.Micro) e [Reactive.UI](https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui). Mas esses frameworks não deixam ele com todo o visual do Github for Windows. Muitas coisas a equipe fez na mão.

**No caso do Visual Studio**, como [@Almeida disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/471/como-criar-uma-interface-de-usuario-com-o-mesmo-estilo-que-foi-utilizado-no-visu/3405#3405), é usando WPF e temas ou customizações. Você não vai achar fácil o *mesmo* tema da Microsoft dando sopa por aí, nem pago, no máximo temas semelhantes.

Um semelhante é o [Modern UI for WPF Templates](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a4362a7-fe5d-4f9d-bc7b-0c0dc272fe31). Você vai ter que procurar templates existentes até achar um que te agrade mesmo.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Parabéns pela primeira medalha Necromante do SOpt por essa pergunta!

Comment: nossa, obrigada!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você esteja se referindo à Metro UI.

[No site da Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/apps/br229519) há a documentação e exemplos.

Comment: Não acho que seja a Metro UI. Os aplicativos rodam com o mesmo visual em versões anteriores do Windows e em modo desktop, não podem estar usando uma API exclusiva do Windows 8. Posso estar enganado.

Answer (score 1):

O Visual Studio é feito em WPF com customizações normais que qualquer usuário pode fazer (inclusive usa temas).
O Office se não me engano ainda é feito em WinForms, e nesse ponto o Ribbon dele é melhor que do WPF.
E o GitHub parece ser WPF customizado pra ficar com cara de Metro (com WPF dá pra fazer praticamente tudo, basta ter paciência pra ficar customizando os componentes).

Answer (score 1):

Não é exatamente o que você está querendo, mas dependendo do tipo de aplicação que está se desenvolvendo, é possível utilizar o Visual Studio Shell, e só criar os plugins para a aplicação.
Aí o programa fica exatamente com a cara do Visual Studio e possui as funcionalidades desejadas.